# Building Maven site on multi-module project causes NPE

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

I am trying to create a *Maven* website for my enterprise project with numerous sub-modules but am unable to because of receiving a constant Null Pointer Exception (NPE). I tried with these two commands:

- `mvn site`
- `mvn site -DskipTests=true`

In both cases the code throws the NPE. Here is the error output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.187 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-02T14:36:50-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/271M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project Foo: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project Foo: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AnalyzeReportMojo.executeReport(AnalyzeReportMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Is the error in the root pom.xml file? I looked at a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-644 but I do not think that this affects me since I am using **Maven 3.3.3**.

0_o

Thank-you for reading this.

Comment: Did you add the site URL like the [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-644) mentioned? Just in case the bug's still there.

Comment: I tried once and received the same thing. I tried changing to Maven 3.0.5 and still received the same error as well. :/

Comment: It looks like I am using 3.3 version of the `site` plug-in. The `site` goal does not require an explicit plugin dependency defined. The parent `pom.xml` has loads of elements with numerous dependencies though...